# How to get a handle to current spec from beforeEach in jasmine test?

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I understand that currentSpec reference is no longer available in beforeEach from jasmine 2.0.0
(Ref: https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/issues/492)

Is there an alternative to find the current Spec or Suite(a nested suite) in beforeEach?

Thanks,
vj.

Comment: Why do you want access to the internal jasmine state of which jasmine spec object is being run? As a consumer, there shouldn't be a need to access this, that's why it's now hidden.

Comment: Hi Gregg,
I have a common beforeEach for my suite with multi-level nested describes in it.
There are only a few specs within these nested describe blocks which need a different logic for their beforeEach.For these specs,I do not want my root level beforeEach logic to be executed.
I am trying to see if there's a clean way of making my root level beforeEach execute a specific logic based on the spec it is running for.

Comment: have you tried using a reporter?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a reporter

```
describe("outer", function() {

  var specDescription, specFullName;

  (function() {
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter({
      suiteStarted: function(result) {
        specDescription = result.description;
        specFullName = result.fullName;
      }
    });
  })();

  beforeEach(function() {
    console.debug(specDescription);
    console.debug(specFullName);
  });


  describe("test1", function() {
    it("bla bla", function() {});
  });
  describe("test2", function() {
    it("bla bla", function() {});
  });
}
```